# @Autowired doesn't work if applied to a bean shared between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, spring-3, autowired

I have some troubles with a very basic scenario: I have a java web app (spring 3) and I want to store some object to a stack. Then I want to manage the objects in the stack with a scheduler and so I implemented a quartz job. Plain and simple. I inject the stack in the first service class and in the job class with @Autowired annotation. For the service class the table is succesfully injected but for the job class the table is null.
here's the code:

the class to share

```
package it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.data;
@Component
public class IndexedNodesStack extends HashMap<IndexedObject, Boolean>{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public synchronized int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.size();
    }

    //all the HashMap methods are implemented in a synchronized wrapper method

}
```

the first class (@Autowired is successful)

```
package it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.service;
@Service
public class InnerNodeManager extends ConcreteNodeManager{

    @Autowired
    private IndexedNodesStack indexedNodesStack; //<--- it is actually autowired!


    private void manageIndexedNodes(Boolean isPut, String lri, String features)
    {
        IndexedObject indexedObject = new IndexedObject();
        indexedObject.setId(lri);
        if(features != null && isPut)
            indexedObject.generateFeatures(features);

        indexedNodesStack.put(indexedObject, isPut);
    }

}
```

the job class (@Autowired fails)

```
package it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.service.scheduler;
@Component
public class QuartzJSearchJob extends QuartzJobBean{

    @Autowired
    private IndexedNodesStack indexedNodesStack; //<--- this variable is null :-(

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        //do work       
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** here's the servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.unifi.det.telemat.vr" />

<bean name="searchJob"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.service.scheduler.QuartzJSearchJob" />
</bean>

<bean id="searchJobTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="searchJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/50 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="searchJobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

maybe I lack some knowledge about the resource sharing between threads since it is my first attempt in this field.
What am I missing?

Comment: you'll need to show how you're creating the object to explain why it wouldn't be properly initialized by spring. how is it being initialized?

Comment: the job is created via @Component annotation (I edited my question to correct it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, finally I get the point.
It doesn't works becaouse spring does not instantiate the quartzJSearchJob, quartz does. The beans to inject inside the job have to be passed via `SchedulerFacoryBean`.
Here's the configuration that makes the things work.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchJobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
    <map>
       <entry key="indexedNodesStack" value-ref="indexedNodesStack" />
    </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Autowiring only works if the bean is created from Spring bean factory. Did you create the object without using bean factory, i.e. create it using `new QuartzJSearchJob()` syntax?

Comment: I try to create it with @Component annotation

Comment: Can you post your bean configuration? Adding @Component does not help if the bean is not create by bean factory.

Comment: can you try to use `setBeanName` instead of `setJobClass` with the value of the bean name, e.g. `quartzJSearchJob`?

Comment: I tried but the scheduler doesn't trigger anything. Is it a clue for something? Here's what I did: 
`<bean id="quartzJSearchJob"
 class="it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.service.scheduler.QuartzJSearchJob">
 </bean>

 <bean name="searchJob"
 class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
  <property name="beanName" value="quartzJSearchJob" />
 </bean>`

Comment: Try adding a method that check if the field is autowired properly in QuartzJSearchJob and annotate the method with @PostConstruct annotation. If it is autowired properly, the problem is about setting up Quartz and I don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

`QuartzJSearchJob` isn't recognized as a bean, because it doesn't have a class level annotation.  Try `@Component`

Comment: my fault, I omitted the @Component in the paste operation while it was actually present in the code. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You forget the "jobDetails" property :

```
<property name="jobDetails">
    <list>
        <ref bean="searchJob" />
    </list>
</property>
```

You also need to use `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean`.

Insert it like this :

```
<bean name="searchJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="it.unifi.det.telemat.vr.service.scheduler.QuartzJSearchJob" />
</bean>

<bean id="searchJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="searchJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/50 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchJobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="searchJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, I resolved this by adding `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` as first line of my `Job.execute(JobExecutionContext context)` method.

Answer (score -2):

I think you must assign a value in `scheduleFactoryBean`, `setSchedulerContextAsMap()`, you put your object in this map, then it will work.

```
@Bean(name = "scheduler")
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory()
  {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    schedulerFactory.setAutoStartup(true);
    schedulerFactory.setGlobalJobListeners(globalJobListeners);
    schedulerFactory.setSchedulerContextAsMap(contextMap());
    schedulerFactory.setQuartzProperties(schedulerProperties());
    return schedulerFactory;
  }
```